# Curve approximation from regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, curve

I am trying to find the tangent vector of a curve. The equation of the curve is a question, I have different points, and based on these points I am looking for an approximation of the function, that describes the curve and fits the points.

When I plot my data it looks like this:
[image]

After applying polynomial regression (based on this article: https://www.statology.org/curve-fitting-in-r/) I get the following result:

```
fit <- lm(cl2[,3] ~ poly(cl2[,2], 3))
    summary(fit)
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = cl2[, 3] ~ poly(cl2[, 2], 3))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.31834 -0.10187  0.02132  0.09577  0.27393 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        -109.89121    0.03789 -2900.217  < 2e-16 ***
poly(cl2[, 2], 3)1    7.33365    0.16516    44.403  < 2e-16 ***
poly(cl2[, 2], 3)2   -4.43572    0.16516   -26.857 4.25e-14 ***
poly(cl2[, 2], 3)3    1.14772    0.16516     6.949 4.66e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1652 on 15 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9946,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9935 
F-statistic: 913.7 on 3 and 15 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

When I fit the curve, the result looks ok:

```
lines(cl2[,2], predict(fit, data.frame(cl2[,2:3])))
```

[image]

Based on the coefficient s I would assume that the equation of the curve is:

1.14*x**3-4.43*x**2+7.33*x-109

When I calculate the y estimates I get very strange numbers:

y_actual:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOWTp.png) -108.4569 -108.1504 -108.0895 -108.0728 -108.0461 -108.1777 -108.2751 -108.4619 -108.6918
[10] -108.9750 -109.3552 -109.7625 -110.3328 -110.9580 -111.4312 -112.0062 -112.7337 -113.5880
[19] -114.3681

y_predicted:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOWTp.png) -8935267 -8980331 -9044297 -9115821 -9166614 -9270340 -9355643 -9456574 -9533497 -9602089
[11] -9631113 -9670175 -9715100 -9754453 -9798813 -9851816 -9880888 -9926067 -9940310

What is wrong here?

I tried setting the raw variable of poly function to TRUE and I got different coefficients, but the problem persists.

---

## Edit

Data in `dput` format

```
y_actual <-
c(-108.4569, -108.1504, -108.0895, -108.0728, -108.0461, -108.1777, 
-108.2751, -108.4619, -108.6918, -108.975, -109.3552, -109.7625, 
-110.3328, -110.958, -111.4312, -112.0062, -112.7337, -113.588, 
-114.3681)

y_predicted <-
c(-8935267, -8980331, -9044297, -9115821, -9166614, -9270340, 
-9355643, -9456574, -9533497, -9602089, -9631113, -9670175, -9715100, 
-9754453, -9798813, -9851816, -9880888, -9926067, -9940310)
```

EDIT:

```
x_values <- c(-197.3419, -197.6753, -198.1467, -198.6710, -199.0418, -199.7946, -200.4095, -201.1323, -201.6797, -202.1654, -202.3702, -202.6451, -202.9605, -203.2359, -203.5455, -203.9142, -204.1158, -204.4285, -204.5268)
```

PROBLEM SOLUTION:

Thank you all for the valuable input. It helped a lot.

I came up with the following function:

```
#find tangent line
tangent_xy <- function(point_index, centerline){
  #fit the polynomial regression
  fit <- lm(centerline[,3] ~ poly(centerline[,2], 3, raw = T))
  # get coefficients
  cf <- fit$coefficients
  # equation of fitted curve
  (eq <- paste(sprintf('%s*x^%s', cf, seq_along(cf) - 1L), collapse='+'))
  # first derivative of fitted curve
  f <- D(parse(text = eq), "x")
  # calculate slope (value of derivative at given point)
  slope <- eval(f, envir = list(x = cl2[point_index,2]))
  #get coordinates of point
  x0 <- centerline[point_index, 2]
  y0 <- centerline[point_index, 3]
  # equation of tangent line
  y = slope*centerline[,2]-slope*x0+y0
  # points for plotting with lines function
  return(y)
}
```

Using the function like this:

```
curve(ff, min(cl2[,2]), max(cl2[,2]))
lines(cl2[,2], tangent_xy(3, cl2))
lines(cl2[,2], tangent_xy(12, cl2))
lines(cl2[,2], tangent_xy(15, cl2))
lines(cl2[,2], tangent_xy(7, cl2))
```

I get the following output:

[image: Curve with tangents]

It is not perfect, however I only need the approximation, so it will do. I will look into GAMs as Roland suggested. Maybe those will work better.

Comment: You might need more decimals places on your coefficients you got from your curve fit. x^3 is about 8000000. Alternatively you could scale x and y to smaller ranges (like divide them by 100).

Comment: Add “raw=TRUE” to the poly function. See the help for an explanation.

Comment: Can you post `x_actual`?

Comment: @Dave2e is correct. The explanation is that the default for poly is to use an orthogonal basis to minimize the risk of falsely concluding that the correlations induced by the "raw" method are meaningful.

Comment: "I am trying to find the tangent vector of a curve." Your code is not attempting to derive a tangent. Does this quote accurately describe your goal? I wouldn't use polynomial regression here.

Comment: I did not include the code for derivation, because the equation for the curve did not produce the expected result. But that is what I intend to do now. What approach would you use?

Comment: If I can't derive a non-linear model from the subject matter or literature, I would fit a `mgcv::gam`. You don't provide x values. So, I can't show you.

Comment: I edited the question to include the x values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate equation from `coef`ficients, use `sprintf` for power series. `parse`d into a function, we may plot it using `curve` over the `points`.

```
> cf <- lm(cl2[, 3] ~ poly(cl2[, 2], 3, raw=TRUE)) |> coef()
> (eq <- paste(sprintf('%s*x^%s', cf, seq_along(cf) - 1L), collapse='+'))
[1] "-2007.84158109665*x^0+-24.0105660224912*x^1+-0.0949876187837792*x^2+-0.000111799887426291*x^3"
> f <- eval(parse(text=paste('\\(x)', eq)))
> curve(f, min(cl2[, 2]), max(cl2[, 2]), col=2, panel.first=points(cl2[, -1]))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
cl2 <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, -205, -204, -203, -202, -201, -200, -199, -198, -197, -196, 
-195, -194, -193, -192, -191, -190, -189, -188, -187, -114.3681, 
-113.588, -112.7337, -112.0062, -111.4312, -110.958, -110.3328, 
-109.7625, -109.3552, -108.975, -108.6918, -108.4619, -108.2751, 
-108.1777, -108.0461, -108.0728, -108.0895, -108.1504, -108.4569
), dim = c(19L, 3L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("", "x", "y")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example in code.  I approximated the x values since there were not provided. My comment above stands: "Use `raw=TRUE` for the nonorthogonal polynomials".

The blue line is are the predicted values from the predict function.  While the red line is using the coefficients from the fit.  Notice the green lines are using the same coefficients but rounded to 5 significant digits and is producing a slightly different curve.
This is the problem with high order equations, a slight difference is multiplied out to become a large difference. A chaotic system.

```
y_actual <-
   c(-108.4569, -108.1504, -108.0895, -108.0728, -108.0461, -108.1777, 
     -108.2751, -108.4619, -108.6918, -108.975, -109.3552, -109.7625, 
     -110.3328, -110.958, -111.4312, -112.0062, -112.7337, -113.588, 
     -114.3681)

#approximating the x values
x<- rev(seq(-204.5, -197, length.out=19))

fit <- lm(y_actual ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE))
summary(fit)

# Call:
#    lm(formula = y_actual ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE))
# 
# Residuals:
#    Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
# -0.123971 -0.030200 -0.000881  0.033129  0.075555 
# 
# Coefficients:
#    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept)             -1.924e+04  1.086e+04  -1.771   0.0968 .
# poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)1 -2.537e+02  1.623e+02  -1.563   0.1390  
# poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)2 -1.099e+00  8.087e-01  -1.359   0.1942  
# poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)3 -1.546e-03  1.343e-03  -1.151   0.2678  
# ---
#    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.05382 on 15 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.9994,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9993 
# F-statistic:  8647 on 3 and 15 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

y_predicted <- predict(fit, data.frame(x))

#plotting the prediction
plot(x, y_actual)
lines(x, y_predicted, col="blue", lwd=3)

#plotting the prediction with the coefficients 
y_pred_2 <- fit$coefficients[4]*x**3 + fit$coefficients[3]*x**2 + fit$coefficients[2]*x + fit$coefficients[1]
lines(x, y_pred_2+0.001, col="red")

#round the coefficents
y_pred_3 <- -1.5455E-3*x**3 - 1.09927*x**2 - 253.68*x - 19238
lines(x, y_pred_3, col="green")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a GAM if you do not have a science-based model and need to do this empirically.

```
DF <- data.frame(x = x_values, y = y_actual)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point()

library(mgcv)

fit <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = DF)
summary(fit)
plot(fit)

p + stat_function(fun = \(x) predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x)), n = 1e3)
```

[image: plot showing the data and the GAM fit]

```
GAMderivative <- function(fit, x0, eps = 1e-7) {
  #finite difference method
  Y0 <- predict(fit, data.frame(x = x0)) 
  Y1 <- predict(fit, data.frame(x = x0 + eps)) 
  dydx <- (Y1-Y0)/eps
  setNames(dydx, x0)
}

GAMderivative(fit, x0 = c(-203, -201, -199))
#     -203      -201      -199 
#1.7973066 0.3248605 0.1396629
```